# WebSite creates two resources

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I noticed that when I create a WebSite (asp.net core 1.0 + angular2) on the Azure Web Console, it creates two resources:

[image]

The fist-one is an **ASP.NET web application - PREVIEW**. What does it mean?
Moreover I selected my **Resource group** (Europe) but Azure creates it in US. Is it normal?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Resource Group is a *logical* container for grouping Azure resources (services), so Resource Group can have other region items. You might miss region selection combobox while creating ASP.NET app service.

In your figure, first one is the icon of [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-started/) and second is your ASP.NET app.

Application Insights is a kind of telemetry service that Azure offer. I recommend you to use (It's cool). You can monitor your application’s availability, performance, reliability, exceptions, usage trends, etc.

When you create a new web app using Visual Studio or the Azure portal, you *automatically* get an Application Insights. You can choose not to add Application Insight during project creation wizard steps.